# Angularjs $watch provides the latest input even when all the information was deleted

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Have any way around this? Is there a better solution? Simulation: http://plnkr.co/edit/2vRT8O?p=preview

**Context:** In my case the inputs are used as filters, and the information entered by the user will be used in searches. The $ watches are used to capture this information and move to a service which in turn passes into a second controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it is enough to check if the old and the new values are not equal? Like this:

```
if (newValue != oldValue) {
   $scope.bar = newValue;
}
```

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ooh1am?p=preview

Comment: Do we need the if condition at all?

Comment: @Codezilla i think `if` is here to prevent a reaction on the  `newValue==oldValue==undefined` situation

Comment: @Codezilla, Cherniv is correct. This is the purpose of the if